# Relation between Axiom of Foundation and $\in$-induction

Tags: set-theory, induction, axiom-of-choice, axioms

At the end of an intro to set theory course, we were introduced the Axiom of Foundation and the Principle of $\in$-induction as one of its consequences. I found it easy to prove that, assuming the Axiom of Choice, $\in$-induction implies the Axiom of Foundation, and I am wondering whether this is also true without Choice. I asked my professor and he spent a good bit of time trying to find out the answer to no avail.

Comment: I have to admit that this question is a bit odd. Where in the proof would you have used the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 2):

Choice has nothing to do with this equivalence, but the law of excluded middle has everything to do with it.

In $\sf ZF$, assuming $\in$-induction, consider the statement "every transitive $y$ such that $x\in y$ is well founded". If all the elements of $x$ satisfy this statement, then any transitive $y$ such that $x\in y$ must be well founded as well. So, the statement holds for all $x$, and easily this implies the Axiom of Foundation.

In the other direction, we can simply translate this to an induction on the rank and appeal to Replacement as necessary.

Comment: Perhaps carfog is thinking about the equivalence of Foundation to the assertion that there are no infinite descending $\in$ chains. In one direction that requires Dependent Choice, yes?

Comment: Indeed, that would require DC.

Comment: The steps are: 1) If the transitive closure of every element is well-founded, so is the transitive closure of the set, as it is the union of these, and for every subset you take its intersection with the closure of any one element, it has a minimal element, and transitivity makes it the minimal element of the whole closure. 2) If the transitive closure of a set is well-founded, the set has an $\in$-minimal element, as it is a subset of its transitive closure. Right?

Comment: I think there has been quite a misunderstanding on my side. We proved Foundation $\rightarrow$ $\in$-induction in class, my proof of the other direction used $\neg$Foundation $\rightarrow$ existence of infinite descending $\in$ chains and thus needed choice. I asked this question to the professor and his first idea was your proof, but he convinced himself and us that it does not work. On looking at it again, it should. Also another proof that should not require choice is proving by $\in$-induction that every set is in V and that Foundation is true in V. Which he mentioned briefly.

Comment: @carfog: Yes, that is the general idea for the first comment. As for the second comment, descending sequences *do* require a modicum of choice, but it has nothing to do with induction. Indeed, the proof that a relation admits an induction schema if and only if it is well-founded requires no choice whatsoever (it is just, admittedly, slightly easier to argue that a descending sequence would be a counterexample to the induction).